# IF statement To Check If DataSet Is Empty

Tags: powershell

I am filling my data set with this `$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)` then assigning the returned results to my variable like so `$rowCount = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)`  Then using an if statement to determine if the rowcount is > 0 `if($rowCount > 0)` BUT my code never executes the if statement.  It returns on screen 3 rows returned from my `.Fill` but that's it.  Full code below:

```
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$rowCount = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
if($rowCount > 0)
{
  [System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory("C:\Data\")
}
```

Comment: the "greater than" comparsion operator in PowerShell is `-gt`, not `>`

Comment: Also check your disk for the file(s) named "0". Presumably `$rowCount > 0` redirects to a file "0" in the current location, see this test [Tempting-wrong-operators/test.2.gt.ps1](https://github.com/nightroman/PowerShellTraps/blob/master/Basic/Tempting-wrong-operators/test.2.gt.ps1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Greater than" in PowerShell syntax is `-gt`. Try this:

```psh
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$rowCount = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
if($rowCount -gt 0)
{
  [System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory("C:\Data\")
}
```

[This link](http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/powershell-tutorial-conditional-logic/) is quite helpful in terms of if and syntax for PowerShell.